# Lightbox no longer works after jQuery pagination is triggered (jQuery and lightbox conflict)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, lightbox

We are using two scripts at the same time: [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and [jQuery pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination). When the page first loads, both of the scripts are working. However, when I click on Page 2 of the pagination, the lightbox no longer shows but I can still go from one page to the next. These are the initialization scripts for both:

**jQuery Pagination:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            // This is a very simple demo that shows how a range of elements can
            // be paginated.
            // The elements that will be displayed are in a hidden DIV and are
            // cloned for display. The elements are static, there are no Ajax 
            // calls involved.

            /**
             * Callback function that displays the content.
             *
             * Gets called every time the user clicks on a pagination link.
             *
             * @param {int} page_index New Page index
             * @param {jQuery} jq the container with the pagination links as a jQuery object
             */
            function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
                var new_content = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
                $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
                return false;
            }

            /** 
             * Initialisation function for pagination
             */
            function initPagination() {
                // count entries inside the hidden content
                var num_entries = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
                // Create content inside pagination element
                $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
                    callback: pageselectCallback,
                    items_per_page:1 // Show only one item per page
                });
             }

            // When document is ready, initialize pagination
            $(document).ready(function(){                  
                initPagination();
            });
</script>
```

**prettyPhoto:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```

Anyone knows where the conflict lies? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem (which I found on another forum):

I just need to insert $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); inside the function pageselectCallback like so:

```
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
                var new_content = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
                $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
                return false;
            }
```

If I could only give +1 to the guy who answered it [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=63274). :)

Answer (score 1):

try using Jquery [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("a").delegate("[rel^='prettyPhoto']", "load", function()
    {

        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

    });
```

Comment: Still doesn't show. I tried putting this in between <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>.